# Oracle: is ROWID a NUMBER or a VARCHAR?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, is `ROWID` a `NUMBER` or a `VARCHAR`?

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 9):

Neither. ROWID is a `ROWID`:

- http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID

Answer (score 4):

Technically, ROWID has its own datatype (also called ROWID or UROWID for IOTs).  If you absolutely must use either NUMBER or VARCHAR datatypes, it will have to be a VARCHAR as the ROWIDs will contain more than just numbers.